simplified form for CDF of inverse Gaussian function, as function of the drift parameter
I am thinking about modelling the probability of an event as a waiting time for a Brownian motion with drift to pass a certain barrier. Then consider what the expression for that probability looks like as drift. Is that expression related to some more well known function (e.g. like the ones used in certain types of binomial regression)?
For a Brownian motion with positive drift $\nu$ variance $\sigma^2$ and starting at zero, the first passage time at positive distance $a$ is distributed as $IG\left(\mu =\frac{a}{\nu}, \lambda = \left(\frac{a}{\sigma}\right)^2  \right)$. Then the passage probability at time $t$ is computed via the CDF.
Can we simplify the expression into a form that is being used for binomial regression?

The probability of passage can be expressed with $\Phi$ the CDF of the normal distribution
$$\begin{array}{}
P(T>t) &=&\Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{t}} \left(\frac{t}{\mu}-1\right)\right) +\exp \left(\frac{2\lambda}{\mu}\right)\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{t}} \left(\frac{t}{\mu}+1\right)\right) \\
&=& \Phi\left(A+B \nu\right) +\exp \left(\frac{2a\nu}{\sigma^2}\right)\Phi\left(A-B\nu\right) 
\end{array}$$
with parameters
$$\begin{array}{}
A &=& - \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{\sigma^2t}} \\
B &=&  \sqrt{\frac{t}{\sigma^2}} \\
\end{array}$$
This looks for example like:

This looks more exotic than I had expected. I had thought that some drift process might have been a reasonable model for some processes that are typically modeled with logistic regression.
If the distance $a$ is large, then it becomes approximately a probit function
$$P(T>t)\approx \Phi\left(A+B \nu\right) $$
For example

